# php how to replace variabla text in url

Tags: php

i have a url and it has a variable part.

for example;

```
www.google.com/helloreddit.html?variabletexthere99848343thereisanothertext
```

`variabletexthere99848343` -> the numbers changing everytime.

i want to delete this part of url and i want to convert url to this ->

```
www.google.com/helloreddit.html?thereisanothertext
```

how can i do that?

Comment: The code you posted is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` with a regular expression that matches the pattern of your variable text.

Comment: @Barmar i have something like that is it regex? \?.*|

Comment: More like `variabletexthere\d{8}`

Comment: @Barmar i want to delete "variabletexthere" too. my url should be like this www.google.com/helloreddit.html?thereisanothertext

Comment: So you want to delete the whole GET-string?

Comment: Are you using PHP or JavaScript? The question is tagged PHP, but the code you posted is JS.

Comment: @Barmar im trying to edit a .php file in wordpress plugin

Comment: So why did you post JS?

Comment: @killahaqan That's why `variabletexthere` is at the beginning of the regular expression, so it will be removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()`.

```
$url = 'www.google.com/helloreddit.html?variabletexthere99848343thereisanothertext';
$url = preg_replace('/variabletexthere\d{8}/', '', $url);
echo $url;
```

`\d` matches a digit, and `{8}` means to match that 8 times in a row. If it's not always exactly 8 digits, you can use `\d+` instead, to match at least 1 digit.